# example of extending Connection object in jsPlumb

Tags: jsplumb

Could anyone provide an example of extending/subclassing Connection object? The only bit of information I found in docs was:

> **getDefaultConnectionType**
>
> Returns the default Connection type.  Used when someone wants to subclass Connection and have jsPlumb return instances of their subclass. you would make a call like this in your class’s constructor:
>
> `jsPlumb.getDefaultConnectionType().apply(this, arguments);`
>
> **Returns**
>
> the default Connection function used by jsPlumb.

This sounds a little vague to me. Ideally I'd like to be able to use my subclass like this:

```
jsPlumb.addEndpoint(element, {
    connector: ["MyConnector", { curviness: 65 }]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK apparently I don't understand the difference between Connection and Connector, but anyways, extending Connection works fine like this:

```
var MyConnection = function (params) {
    params.label = "bingo!";
    jsPlumb.getDefaultConnectionType().apply(this, arguments);
};


jsPlumb.Defaults.ConnectionType = MyConnection;
```